# Can "reopen" be used as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, american-english

If there is a retail store that closes temporarily due to remodeling and then it is opened again, might the store owner send out a mailing that says "Your store is now reopen!" or would that not make any sense?

Comment: Sounds horrid to me.  What's wrong with "reopened"?

Comment: I'd rather use "your store is now open" or  "Your store has now reopened"

Comment: Oh we all agree that it SOUNDS better the other way, but is it incorrect grammatically?

Comment: reopen is not an adjective, so I guess  not, but I'm not a grammar buff. Open is a verb but also the adjectival form , so you can say The store is open but not The store is reopen.

Comment: I imagine some software may have two buttons, the close button and the reopen button.  But you probably would still not call it an adjective.

Comment: You push a button to request an action (open the program/reopen the program), therefore you could argue that it's a verb

Comment: *Would that not make any sense?* Since when has "correct" use of English had any connection with "making sense"?

Comment: That's a good point...I guess I mean would it make any sense grammatically :)

Comment: I'd say "Your store has reopened."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reopen" is not a validly formed adjective. Per the Wikipedia article on [English prefixes](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prefix):

> the prefix re- meaning "again, back" is only added to verb bases as in rebuild, reclaim, reuse, resell, re-evaluate, resettle. It cannot be added to bases of other lexical categories. Thus, examples of re- plus a noun base (such as the ungrammatical *rehusband, *remonopoly) or re- plus an adjective base (*renatural, *rewise) are virtually unattested.

So even though "open" by itself can be a verb or an adjective, the prefix "re-" can only be added to the verb.

Comment: _Rehusband_ seems perfectly valid to me—but using _husband_ as a verb, of course, rather than a noun.